# Making tree diagram fit multiple per row

Tags: multicol, qtree

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage,amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,nicefrac, amsthm,calc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{qtree}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\newpage
\begin{enumerate}
\item 
{\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
$8$ & $11$ & $9$ & $6$ & $7$ & $2$ & $4$ & $5$ & $10$ & $1$ & $3$ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\Tree[.8 [.11 [.6 [.5 ] [.10 ]] [.7 [.1 ] [.3 ]]]
               [.9   [.2 ] [.4 ]]]
}

\medskip
\medskip
\medskip
\medskip
\medskip

{\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
$8$ & $11$ & $9$ & $6$ & $1$ & $2$ & $4$ & $5$ & $10$ & $7$ & $3$ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\Tree[.8 [.11 [.6 [.5 ] [.10 ]] [.1 [.7 ] [.3 ]]]
               [.9   [.2 ] [.4 ]]]
}

\medskip
\medskip
\medskip
\medskip
\medskip

{\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
$8$ & $11$ & $9$ & $5$ & $1$ & $2$ & $4$ & $6$ & $10$ & $7$ & $3$ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\Tree[.8 [.11 [.5 [.6 ] [.10 ]] [.1 [.7 ] [.3 ]]]
               [.9   [.2 ] [.4 ]]]
}

\medskip
\medskip
\medskip
\medskip
\medskip

{\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
$8$ & $11$ & $2$ & $5$ & $1$ & $9$ & $4$ & $6$ & $10$ & $7$ & $3$ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\Tree[.8 [.11 [.5 [.6 ] [.10 ]] [.1 [.7 ] [.3 ]]]
               [.2   [.9 ] [.4 ]]]
}

\medskip
\medskip
\medskip
\medskip
\medskip

{\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
$8$ & $1$ & $2$ & $5$ & $3$ & $9$ & $4$ & $6$ & $10$ & $7$ & $11$ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\Tree[.8 [.1 [.5 [.6 ] [.10 ]] [.3 [.7 ] [.11 ]]]
               [.2   [.9 ] [.4 ]]]
}

\medskip
\medskip
\medskip
\medskip
\medskip

{\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
$1$ & $3$ & $2$ & $5$ & $7$ & $9$ & $4$ & $6$ & $10$ & $8$ & $11$ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\Tree[.1 [.3 [.5 [.6 ] [.10 ]] [.7 [.8 ] [.11 ]]]
               [.2   [.9 ] [.4 ]]]
}

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

I feel like the trees are taking up too much space, so I want to have them two columns per row instead of one per row. It would also be good if I could number them somehow, or otherwise be able to indicate the order explicitly. How can I achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: @cfr edited! added some packages.

Comment: Also, do you need to refer to the numbers or do they just need to indicate the order within the diagram?

Comment: @cfr Ok, now it should definitely work

Comment: Heap sort, is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

[image: ticker trees]

This uses a new command `\ticker{<numbers for ticker tape>}{<code for tree>}`. (I only used `\ticker` because it looks like ticker tape to me.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{qtree}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\newcounter{tapes}
\newcommand*\ticker[2]{%
  \refstepcounter{tapes}%
  \noindent\thetapes.
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \tikz{%
      \coordinate (n0) at (0,0);
      \foreach \i [count=\j, remember=\j as \k (initially 0)] in {#1} \node (n\j) [anchor=south west, draw, text width=12.5pt, text centered, inner ysep=2.5pt, inner xsep=2.5pt, xshift=-\pgflinewidth] at (n\k.south east)  {\i};
    }\par
    #2\medskip\par
  \end{minipage}%
}
\ticker{8,11,9,6,7,2,4,5,10,1,3}{%
  \Tree[.8 [.11 [.6 [.5 ] [.10 ]] [.7 [.1 ] [.3 ]]]
  [.9   [.2 ] [.4 ]]]}\hfill
\ticker{8,11,9,6,1,2,4,5,10,7,3}{%
  \Tree[.8 [.11 [.6 [.5 ] [.10 ]] [.1 [.7 ] [.3 ]]]
  [.9   [.2 ] [.4 ]]]}

\ticker{8,11,9,5,1,2,4,6,10,7,3}{%
  \Tree[.8 [.11 [.5 [.6 ] [.10 ]] [.1 [.7 ] [.3 ]]]
  [.9   [.2 ] [.4 ]]]}\hfill
\ticker{8,11,2,5,1,9,4,6,10,7,3}{%
  \Tree[.8 [.11 [.5 [.6 ] [.10 ]] [.1 [.7 ] [.3 ]]]
  [.2   [.9 ] [.4 ]]]}

\ticker{8,1,2,5,3,9,4,6,10,7,11}{%
  \Tree[.8 [.1 [.5 [.6 ] [.10 ]] [.3 [.7 ] [.11 ]]]
  [.2   [.9 ] [.4 ]]]}\hfill
\ticker{1,3,2,5,7,9,4,6,10,8,11}{%
  \Tree[.1 [.3 [.5 [.6 ] [.10 ]] [.7 [.8 ] [.11 ]]]
  [.2   [.9 ] [.4 ]]]}
\end{document}
```

## EDIT

This addresses a further question asked in comments, which is how to centre the trees with respect to their roots, as opposed to centring the trees themselves.

I think this would be hard to do with `qtree` unless, perhaps, you hacked the production of the ticker tape into the `\Tree` macro. It is a long time since I used `qtree`, but I remember hacking it not being especially fun. (That is, it was hard to get it to do what it was not intended to be able to do!)

You can stop the trees being centred with `qtree`, but that is not really what is wanted.

To centre the roots relative to the ticker tapes, I suggest abandoning `qtree` and moving to one of the more flexible Ti*k*Z-based tree-drawing packages. `tikz-qtree` is one option; `forest` is another. My preference for the latter will come as no particular surprise on this site.

Here's a Forest solution. `tickertree` is an environment which takes one mandatory argument. This argument should specify the numbers for the ticker tape. The body of the environment should give the tree specification in Forest's bracket syntax.

Then

```
\begin{tickertree}{8,11,9,6,7,2,4,5,10,1,3}
  [8
    [11
      [6
        [5]
        [10]
      ]
      [7
      [1]
      [3]
      ]
    ]
    [9
      [2]
      [4]
    ]
  ]
\end{tickertree}\hfill
\begin{tickertree}{8,11,9,6,1,2,4,5,10,7,3}
  [8[11[6[5][10]][1[7][3]]][9[2][4]]]
\end{tickertree}

\begin{tickertree}{8,11,9,5,1,2,4,6,10,7,3}
  [8[11[5[6][10]][1[7][3]]][9[2][4]]]
\end{tickertree}\hfill
\begin{tickertree}{8,11,2,5,1,9,4,6,10,7,3}
  [8[11[5[6][10]][1[7][3]]][2[9][4]]]
\end{tickertree}

\begin{tickertree}{8,1,2,5,3,9,4,6,10,7,11}
  [8[1[5[6][10]][3[7][11]]][2[9][4]]]
\end{tickertree}\hfill
\begin{tickertree}{1,3,2,5,7,9,4,6,10,8,11}
  [1[3[5[6][10]][7[8][11]]][2[9][4]]]
\end{tickertree}
```

will produce the 6 trees with tickers shown above, with their roots below the midpoint of their respective tapes.

[image: Forest solution for ticker tape trees]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\pagestyle{empty}
\makeatletter
\environbodyname\tickertreebody
\bracketset{action character=@}
\newsavebox\tickertreetape
\newcounter{tapes}
\NewEnviron{tickertree}[1]{%
  \sbox\tickertreetape{%
    \tikz{%
      \coordinate (n0) at (0,0);
      \foreach \i [count=\j, remember=\j as \k (initially 0)] in {#1} \node (n\j) [anchor=south west, draw, text width=12.5pt, text centered, inner ysep=2.5pt, inner xsep=2.5pt, xshift=-\pgflinewidth] at (n\k.south east)  {\i};
    }%
  }%
  \refstepcounter{tapes}%
  \noindent\thetapes.
  \begin{forest}
    before drawing tree={
      !r1.no edge
    },
    before computing xy={
      !r1.l'=\baselineskip,
    }
    [\usebox{\tickertreetape} @\tickertreebody]
  \end{forest}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{tickertree}{8,11,9,6,7,2,4,5,10,1,3}
  [8
    [11
      [6
        [5]
        [10]
      ]
      [7
      [1]
      [3]
      ]
    ]
    [9
      [2]
      [4]
    ]
  ]
\end{tickertree}\hfill
\begin{tickertree}{8,11,9,6,1,2,4,5,10,7,3}
  [8[11[6[5][10]][1[7][3]]][9[2][4]]]
\end{tickertree}

\begin{tickertree}{8,11,9,5,1,2,4,6,10,7,3}
  [8[11[5[6][10]][1[7][3]]][9[2][4]]]
\end{tickertree}\hfill
\begin{tickertree}{8,11,2,5,1,9,4,6,10,7,3}
  [8[11[5[6][10]][1[7][3]]][2[9][4]]]
\end{tickertree}

\begin{tickertree}{8,1,2,5,3,9,4,6,10,7,11}
  [8[1[5[6][10]][3[7][11]]][2[9][4]]]
\end{tickertree}\hfill
\begin{tickertree}{1,3,2,5,7,9,4,6,10,8,11}
  [1[3[5[6][10]][7[8][11]]][2[9][4]]]
\end{tickertree}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is (almost) exactly what I wanted! Is there any way to vertically align each tree with its corresponding ticker?

Comment: @b_pcakes Do you mean vertically so they are side-by-side? Or horizontally, so the tree is beneath the ticker with the root midway along the ticker's length?

Comment: I meant the latter

Comment: @b_pcakes There is no easy way to do this because the trees are centred. They are not symmetrical, so there is more tree on one side of the root than the other. The best solution is probably to use an alternative to `qtree` e.g. a Ti*k*Z-based approach which will allow you to set the ticker and the tree all within the `tikzpicture` environment. I'll see if I can adapt the above to show what I mean.

Comment: @b_pcakes Please see edit above.